# Datastage integration with Source Repository tool

Tags: version-control, datastage

I am looking for help to integrate datastage ETL tool with any source repository tool in automated way. could you please let me know the repository tool name (for ex.- gitlab, github,bitbucket etc) which can directly integrate with Datastage and also please provide process

I tried to find out the way but they integrating through remote git repository I am not looking for that.
I am looking for direct integration.